# Mount ASM Disks To New Host

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-asm

I have oracle 11.2.0.4 installed on Red Hat Linux 6.

I have an RMAN full backup from database that size is  20TB . This backup is created on ASM disks with different diskgroup from `DATA`.

I want to restore this backup to a new host .
For some reasons , I should plug these disks to a new host and then restore it, I have a question :

How can I add these ASM disks to new host ?

I have drop this diskgroup from target host and then with                        `" oracleasm deletedisk "` , unplugged them from OS and then unplugged these disks from target host and the plugging this disk to new hosts that have oracle 11.2.0.4 and Red Hat Linux 6 .

When I run /`etc/init.d/oracleasm scandisks` , scandisk is ok and then when execute `oracleasm listdisks` , these disks are not on listed disks .

Can any one help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

*I have drop this diskgroup from target host and then with  " oracleasm deletedisk "*

This was a mistake. You removed the metadata describing the content. You should have just simply detached the disks, then attach to the new host, leaving the disks intact.